# Вывести все слова начинающиеся на букву "с"

Tags: python

```
import re

string="Я, Вальчук Матвій Олександрович, студент групи Тр-11, Номер за списком 5."
# a)
surname = string[3:10]
name = string[11:17]
patronymic = string[18:31]
print('Прізвище', surname)
print("Ім'я", name)
print('По батькові', patronymic)
# б)
print(string.replace("a","A"))
# в)
print(string.count("т"))
# Г)
print(*filter(lambda x: x.startswith('c'), string))
# Д)
print(string[:len(string)//2].replace("п","*"))
# У)
print(len(string.split()))
```

помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно получить лист:

```
lst=[i for i in str.split() if i.startswith('с')]
```

Если же вам нужно еще и вывести в консоль:

```
lst=[i for i in str.split() if i.startswith('с')]
for i in lst: print(i)
```